# JSON array missing elements

Tags: php, jquery, html, json

I am using the `$.getJSON` jQuery function to allow my site to interact with a server at a different domain. However, I've been stuck fixing a bug which causes the third and fourth data item to be `undefined`. I’m not sure where the problem is.

JavaScript:

```
$.getJSON(domain_path + 'display.php?url=' + purl + '&callback=?', function(data) {

        var username = data['uname'];
        var point = data['point'];
        var email = data['email'];
        var title = data['title'];

});
```

The `email` and `title` are `undefined`, but `uname` and `point` are correct.

JSON is generated by this PHP:

```
$url = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['url']);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user url='$url'")or die(mysql_error()); 
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
if($row){

    $uname = $row['uname'];
    $point = $row['point'];
    $email = $row['email'];
    $title = $row['title'];

    $output = array('uname'=>$uname,'point'=>$point,'email'=>$email,'title'=>$title);
    $out_string =  json_encode($output);
    echo $callback.'('.$out_string.');';
}
```

JSON results look like this:

```
284927410({"uname":"john","point":"104","email":"john482@yahoo.com","title":"teacher"});
```

I am able to get `john` and `104`, but `email` and `title` come up `undefined` when I put them in an `alert()`.

Is there some rule I missed? Or is there something wrong in the code?

Comment: your code looks correct to me. Everything should work as expected

Comment: Side Note: You do not need to reconstruct an `$output` varaible. Just do `$out_string =  json_encode($row);` - also, in JS I use `data.title` instead of `data['title']` - don't think there is a difference, but perhaps its worth trying.

Comment: How and where do you realize that `email` and `title` are undefined. Alert them and data['email'] just after `var email = data['email']; var title = data['title'];`.

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced your environment and everything is working fine using this code:

```
$.getJSON("http://localhost:8081/test", function(data) {
        alert(data.uname);
        alert(data.point);
        alert(data.email);
        alert(data.title);
    });
```

Where the path `http://localhost:8081/test` returns only 
`{"point":"104","title":"teacher","email":"john482@yahoo.com","uname":"john"}`